# Correctly using custom fonts in separate .css stylesheet

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have downloaded on my computer a .ttf file containing the font I want to use. What I would like to do is to apply it to my html page. I am using a separate .css stylesheet to which there's a link inside the head section of my html file.

How exactly do I apply this custom font? I tried using 
@font-face and I have the following code in my .css file, but it won't work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "chosenNameForCustomFont";
    src: url("fonts/customFontName");
}

p {
    font-family: chosenNameForCustomFont;
}
```

The paragraphs in the html file will still be normal, without the font. 
If I put the above code inside the actual html file, within "style" tags, it works. What am I doing wrong then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when I need to do this I use the [fontsquirrell generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). You need to upload the font you need to use and it will generate an example to use it.

After you generate the font kit you'll get a bundle with several files:

```
font_name.eot
font_name.svg
font_name.ttf
font_name.woff
font_name.woff2
font_name-demo.html   <-- Open it
stylesheet.css
```

After you open the .html you'll see your font perfectly working in the sample page. You need to copy all those files (.eot, .svg, .ttf, .woff, .woff2) into your source folder and reference those in your .css (may be you'll need to edit the directory depending on where you put the font files) as the stylesheet.css does:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'font_name';
src: url('/relative/path/font_name-webfont.eot');
src: url('/relative/path/font_name-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/relative/path/font_name-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('/relative/path/font_name-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/relative/path/font_name-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/relative/path/font_name-webfont.svg#fontnameregular')     format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Remember the fonts you are using need to be legally eligible for web embedding.

Hope it helps

Comment: Did that after reading your answer, but still not working when using the code in a separate .css file. I think the problem is in the code itself. Is there an error or something? Some misplaced or wrong quotes?

Comment: Did the generator created a bundle with lots of files?

Comment: Yep, it did. There was a stylesheet file containing links with all the different formats of the font file (ttf, eot, woff, ecc). I copied that code inside my .css file. Not working

Comment: Never mind, solved it. Thanks a lot! (after I copy-pasted the code I unintentionally pressed another key which prevented the code from being correct)

Comment: Perfect! I just explained it a little bit better on my answer. I'm glad to help